# Могут ли web-socket работать на чистом tomcat 8.5.15 без GlassFish

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, glassfish

У меня есть приложение использующее `web-socket` и подключение по сокетам не получается:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Я использую `tomcat 8.5.15` не каких подключений для `GlassFish` я не проводил.

Я так понял что обычно для этого используют `GlassFish` который включает в себя и `tomcat`(Поправьте меня если я не прав). 
Подскажите пожалуйста, `tomcat` может сам использовать `websocket-api` или `GlassFish` необходим?

Comment: В документации к Tomcat пишут что может: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html . Там же есть ссылки на примеры

Comment: @Pavel можно воспользоваться и сторонней библиотекой http://tootallnate.github.io/Java-WebSocket//